# Displaying image that was previously uploaded to server

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, upload

For a project I'm working I would like the user (admin) to be able to change the picture on the page he is currently on. I managed to upload the image to "the server" using [interlink](http://interlink.codeplex.com/). This basicly uploads it to a given folder on a server, in my case being: Interlink/Uploads.

But now I don't really know how can I tell my website to replace the source of the image that is currently shown with the source of the uploaded image.

Another something I would like to do is create a simple image gallery with all the images in that folder, once again I don't know how to do this.

I hope somebody can help me, Thanks.
Thomas

Edit: Just so clarify, the application is written in silverlight (XAML, C#). I apologise for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that the "Silverlight" portion of this question is related only to Interlink (your file uploader), and not to the page itself, which I presume is straight HTML.

If that's the case, you've got several options for changing the local image. The simplest way is simply to wait until you know that your file upload has finished (presumably Interlink has some way of notifying you that this is the case), and then run something like this bit of JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeImage(newImageSource) {
        document.getElementById('myTargetImage').setAttribute('src', newImageSource);
    }
</script>
```

As far as displaying a simple image gallery with all the images in the folder, my recommendation would be to look into one of the numerous jquery plugins that handle this sort of thing, e.g.:

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/

EDIT: Silverlight Options

You basically have the same options, except you're doing them in C# instead of JavaScript. For instance, when Interlink tells you that the new image has been uploaded, run this:

```
string imageName = "something.jpeg";
var ub = new UriBuilder(HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri);
ub.Path = "/Interlink/Uploads/" + imageName;
img.Source = new BitmapImage(ub.Uri);
```

And for an image carousel, something like this:

http://3dimagecarousel.codeplex.com/

You'll just need to provide the URL's of all the images. The easiest way to do that is probably to expose a web service method that lists them all.

Comment: My apologies, the application is completely written in silverlight (eg, xaml) so I have no HTML. I apologise for the inconvenience.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to get the URL from the uploaded image, only documentation I can find is [this](http://interlink.codeplex.com/documentation) . Thank you for your help though.

Comment: Might want to add that as a separate question. The precise answer will depend on a variety of different details. But if the Interlink uploader does in fact put them in a directory called /Interlink/Uploads/ that hangs off of the web server, and if you know the name of the file before the user uploads it, then you should be able to access the file at http://whateveryoururlis.com/Interlink/Uploads/whateverthefilenameis.jpg.